# how to extend washing machine drainage hose such that it doesn't leak

Tags: leak, waterproofing, drainage, washing-machine, drain-waste-vent

I have a [portable washing machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JJZBHK4) that I want to keep in one of our bedrooms and thus need to extend the stock drainage hose. My current solution is:

1. buy the necessary length of clear plastic tubing
2. wrap the existing hose with electrical tape until it barely fits inside the plastic tubing
3. use a hose clamp to cinch down the tubing so that there are no leaks

Unfortunately, my solution does not prevent all leaks; a small bit of water still leaks out.

What are your suggestions?

[image: original drainage hose w/ measurement from ruler][image: original tube with tape and hose clamp]

Comment: Two hose clamps and a scrap of PVC pipe.

Comment: Pvc or copper something that the clamps can lock down on and create a seal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a dishwasher hose drain kit, cutting the 'connector piece' until it just barely fit inside the original drainage hose. I then used a hose clamp to make the seal water tight.

[image: dishwasher drain hose kit]

[image: put new drain hose inside original drain hose]

Answer (score 2):

**Replace this hose with a single long hose.**

Remove the hose that came with the unit and measure the size of the fitting it was attached to. Go to a good hardware or plumbing shop and buy a single length of heavy duty reinforced rubber hose and a hose clamp to fit. This is the only correct way to do it IMO.

Comment: I would like to do this but it requires removing the side panel on my washing machine and I am afraid of breaking something.

Comment: OK, do **not** rely on glue alone as some have suggested. Go to a good hardware/plumbing shop and get a 7/8" *barbed coupling*, and some 7/8" I.D. reinforced rubber hose, and some hose clamps to fit. Then use silicone caulk/glue (or equivalent flexible RTV adhesive) and glue *and* clamp the connection between the two hoses.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to buy some 20mm light duty flexible corrugated conduit from hardware store and pvc electrical conduit glue.run the glue around inside of end of drain hose and around the outside on the end of flexible corrugated conduit.insert conduit in end of drain hose,glue will dry in a few minutes or so and you are good to go with no leaks.or alternitavely you can buy extra long drain hoses from plumbing wholesale stores

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut a piece of 3/4 or 1” pvc pipe (depending on which size fits into the end of each hose) 3” long (to be used as a coupling) and insert them into the end of each hose using 2 hose clamps one for each end of your coupling. You must use a ridged piece of pipe for this connection. Make sure to buy a washing machine discharge hose instead of any other type of hose, this will help reduce the chances of you using the wrong type of hose. Get the idea of sticking one hose into the end of the other hose out of your head because that will not work.

Comment: Barbed fittings and hose clamps don't work for ya?